# How do i efficiently find the distance from a set of lines/rays to a point cloud

Tags: numpy, line, point-clouds, euclidean-distance

How can i efficiently find the euclidean distance from N unbounded rays (parametrized by a point and a direction) and M points in 3D, using Python/Numpy/PyTorch?
The goal is to end up with N distances, from each ray to its nearest point.

The naive solution is to compute the distance between each ray and each point, but this has complexity **O(NM)**.
Does there exist any algorithm that may speed up this query? Perhaps one based on r-trees?

Comment: The solution often use to solve this problem is to use [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). For each ray, you iterate over a subset of the octree recursively so to find the nearest point. The resulting algorithm should run in a time close to `O(n log n)` (probably higher but clearly not O(n m)`). Note that this is far from being easy to implement though.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

I ended up using a ray-marching approximation, based on [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html)

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

def rays_pc_distance(
        ray_origins : np.ndarray, # (N, 3)
        ray_dirs    : np.ndarray, # (N, 3)
        points      : np.ndarray, # (M, 3)
        n_steps     : int = 10,
        ) -> np.ndarray:

    index = BallTree(points)
    min_d = index.query(ray_origins + np.zeros_like(ray_dirs), k=1, return_distance=True)[0]
    acc_d = min_d.copy()
    for _ in range(n_steps):
        current_d = index.query(ray_origins + acc_d * ray_dirs, k=1, return_distance=True)[0]
        np.minimum(current_d, min_d, out=min_d)
        acc_d += current_d #* 0.8    

    return min_d # (N, 1)
```

Please let me know if there is something seriously wrong with this approach.